# How to find intersecting point of 2 rectangles?

Tags: canvas, geometry, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw two rectangle as one shape and include a angle annotation using HTML5 canvas.

The finished version I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

How can I find the intersection point on the inside angle to know where to draw the angle annotation?

```js
let canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
// rectangle dimensions    
let height = 50;
let width = 200;

// starting coordinates
let x = 20;
let y = 20;

// translate to starting coordinates
ctx.translate(x, y);

// draw first rectangle 
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,width,height);

// translate to the end of the first rectangle
ctx.translate(width, 0);

// rotate canvas by 45 degrees
ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);

// draw second rectangle
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,width,height);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=700 height=500></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not attempted much on your code snippet... 
Break down this problem to lines, a rectangle is just 4 lines, and the intersection point of those is basic geometry: https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/geometry-concepts-line-intersection-and-its-applications/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at your two overlaping shapes, we can spot something interesting: the point you want to know and two nearby points form a triangle.

[image]

Let's have a closer look and see which parameters of this triangle we actually know:
[image]

- side c - this is simply the height of the rectangle
- point B - first rectangle's startpoint + it's width
- point A - first rectangle's startpoint + it's width & height
- angle between b & c - 90°
- angle between c & a - as you can see it's exactly half the rotation (45° / 2 = 22.5°)
- angle between b & a - the remainder after subtracting the previous two angles from 180° (67.5°)

Now what we are interested in is **point C**, which is **side b** length away from **point A**.

With all the information given above, we come to the conclusion that this triangle is a so called **ASA** triangle, which means 'Angle, Side, Angle' - as we know two angles and a side between the angles.

According to the **law of sines**, we can obtain side b using this handy equation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's an interactive example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   
let height = 50;
let width = 200;

let x = 20;
let y = 20;
let rotation = 45;
let radius = 30;
let angle;
let missingSide;

function draw() {
  document.getElementById("sliderLabel").innerText = "rotation: " + rotation + "°";
  angle = 180 - 90 - rotation / 2;
  missingSide = (height / Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)) * Math.sin((rotation / 2) * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x + width - missingSide, x + height, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.translate(width, 0);
  ctx.rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.restore();
}
draw();

document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  rotation = parseInt(e.target.value);
  draw();
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="90" value="45" id="slider">
  <label for="slider" id="sliderLabel">Volume</label>
</div><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=440 height=250></canvas>
```

Comment: This is a great explanation and the example code provided is much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words Niall - I'm glad I could help! =)